# Particular NextJS API endpoint not invoked properly

Tags: next.js

I have this bare-bones file structure:

```
./pages/api
└── auth
    └── [...param].ts
```

With `param.ts`:

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  console.log('in api/auth/catchall with query', req.query);
  switch (req.query.param) {
    case 'refresh-token': {
      console.log('refresh-token');
      res.status(200).json({ text: 'refresh-token endpoint called' });
      return res;
    }
    default: {
      res.status(200).json({ text: 'just ' + req.query.param });
      return res;
    }
  }
}
```

When I run my app and browse to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/refresh-token`, nothing will be logged, and I get redirected to `http://localhost:3000` (so it's *not* a `404` as for an non-existent endpoint). For any other url, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/refresh-token2`, the api endpoint behaves as expected: `"in api/auth/catchall with query ..."` is logged, and I get the json as response. Similarly, an endpoint like `api/auth/refresh-token.ts` will show the same, faulty behavior, while every other file in this folder will work as expected. Renaming the `auth/` to anything else helps, too.

I'm wondering which weird setting/side effect in my project I could have missed which causes this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I got it. In the past, I accidentally redirected from this very endpoint to `'/'` with code `308` (i.e., a permanent redirect). Firefox cached that, und didn't request the api endpoint anymore afterward. Temporarily disabling the cache in the dev tools (in the `Network`) and visiting this endpoint made Firefox forget!